# redirect uri mismatch error in OAuth 2.0 Playground

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, oauth2-playground

I enabled YOUTUBE API v3 web application in google cloud console and received `client_id` and `client_secret`.
I even set https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ as `redirect_uris` in my `OAuth consent` app and published my app.
after this steps I tried to get refresh token from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ using `client_id` and `client_secret` but I get following error:
[image: my image]
where is my problem?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFIUpNHsquE

Comment: @Logan I will try it and report result here

Comment: Sure please keep me posted, thanks.

Comment: @Logan not worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one found a solution to this problem but me
I set
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
as redirect uris in google console and latest slash make error!
I must use following as redirect uris in google console :
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground